# expected primary expression before ')' token

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, programming, arduino-ide

```
#define ANALOG_IN 0



void setup() {

  Serial.begin(19200);

  analogReference(INTERNAL);

}



void loop() {

  int val = analogRead(ANALOG_IN);

  Serial.print(0xff, byte);

  Serial.print( (val >> 8) & 0xff, byte);

  Serial.print( val & 0xff, byte);



}
```

This is my code and I'm getting this error for all 3 Serial.print commands. Please help.

Comment: if you want to send a byte use Serial.write()

Answer (score 1):

Why are you putting `byte` there? That isn't in the [Serial.print reference page](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/print/).

This compiles OK:

```
#define ANALOG_IN 0

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(19200);
  analogReference(INTERNAL);
}

void loop() {
  int val = analogRead(ANALOG_IN);
  Serial.print(0xff);
  Serial.print( (val >> 8) & 0xff);
  Serial.print( val & 0xff);
}
```